# nested viewpagers: letting the outer swipe but not the inner

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

**In a nutshell:**

I have a `ViewPager`, `vpOuter` that displays a fragment that has another `ViewPager`, `vpInner`.

The user is supposed to be able to swipe between fragments of `vpOuter` but the fragments displayed with `vpInner` can only be swapped programmatically.

Right now, swiping on `vpInner` does nothing, while swiping outside `vpInner` switches between `vpOuter`'s fragments.

How can I make it so that swiping on `vpInner` is recognised as swiping between `vpOuter`?

(the two `ViewPager`s have no knowledge of each other)

**The full story:**

Alright so I have an activity that has a view pager with three fragments.

Let's call them A, B and C.

Now the user can swipe between them or use a bottom navigation.

`A` is our "viewer fragment" and it displays either something if there's something to display or nothing if there's nothing to display, but it will only ever display a single thing at a time.

`A` contains a non-swipable view pager.

The reasoning behind that is that we want to display text and images and who-knows-what and we create a view fragment for each media type that we want to display. So when we have something to display, we check what that something is, switch to the corresponding fragment and populate it with the data.

As a result, A will look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <[...].android.ui.widgets.NonswipableViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--irrrelevant floating action button here-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

where

```
/**A view pager that disables swiping to switch between pages.
 * Switching must happen programmatically.*/
class NonswipableViewPager:ViewPager{
    constructor(context:Context):super(context)
    constructor(context: Context,attributeSet: AttributeSet):super(context,attributeSet)

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

Let's for a moment pretend that there are only text contents that we want to display.

Then we have two fragments:

```
class NoContentView : AbstractContentView() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A_component_text_view, container, false)
        fragmentView.content.text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.A_nothingToShow))
        return fragmentView
    }

    //more irrelevant stuff here
}
```

which we display when we have nothing to show, and

```
class TextContentView:AbstractContentView(){
    @Volatile private var displayedData:String? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A_component_text_view, container, false)
        displayedData?.let { view.content.text = it }
        return view
    }

    override fun display(c: IDisplayableContent) {
        displayedData = String(c.data, Charsets.UTF_8)
        content?.text = displayedData
    }
}
```

and they both inflate this here layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="PLACEHOLDER" />
    </ScrollView>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

If there's a `TextContentView` being displayed, everything works fine and I can swipe between fragments `A`, `B` and `C` without issues.

However, when the `NoContentView` is being displayed, I need to make a conscious effort to avoid the text content when swiping or else it just won't do anything.

How can I make it always behave as if the unswipable view pager just wasn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is caused by the outer ViewPager sensing that it has scrollable content that can scroll in the same direction, so the outer ViewPager refuses to scroll in that direction.

This can be resolved by overriding `canScrollHorizontally(int direction)` in the inner ViewPager to return false.